# How can I parse a string in JS which is the result of google location api?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Here is the result of ajax request:

```
console.log(locations.output);
/*
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "4c45c924b261e2bb262360fb5a25d4b9a94088a7",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJf5Us9YQBjj8R0OohvHQms1U",
         "reference" : "CjQtAAAA6j_9DtMr30DQ9h8dzemfD2NaWEWBgf5yFlQ92XW4EZvHXqZ8Ob6wGkedetO1xNiZEhCGeIk7jBXCQP_ad4V0R-YeGhSIcGtxcxPh-G4e2DMT97Be4xdfkg",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehran Province",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 17,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "14788d031b564588682273730e2e16d2617d3548",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2dzzH0kAjj8RvCRwVnxps_A",
         "reference" : "CkQ1AAAAGXsNCFct3XK9JukMD-C7D7j1f0b-Rk0uBZFULZ9TKziZVKz2HWeNWZ5xWU-aNIceYEioJRxHmYS_O7DhMW32YBIQzGS_zTt6aijJx_onRU9DTRoU-cPuoOF16KrzlFY_4EGlwVf1Izk",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehran",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Tehran Province, Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehran"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 8,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 25,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Tehranpars, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "09a979a1ac286c1ff2ee94c5d36258910d7f6ec6",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJX5PM9hwdjj8R6zn_mu5suoE",
         "reference" : "ClRBAAAACKbtLWiAm5kV0JzYtPOLhQTuMxlMMIXxPGRmuLUF7xuAlx7Mueo91OuJmB4mTwo3T0NhnNhamVDUsKFE0fNffkZi1Bv-ZQs1TcXLNx195C0SELOTSsOMn6pYeSnFMtvVqsIaFCxWipFk_wIxDKVoLi8Cd8g993cG",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehranpars",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehranpars"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 12,
               "value" : "Tehran"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 20,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 37,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Tehran Now, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "1f7583f258e7e92f03b818ba10c48e20d2bd9f59",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ61k7RLICjj8RnvjuZpbZeEM",
         "reference" : "ClRBAAAAydlnsS8Fjw9ibBXXX-XS4xuY4-7yEqMSZNTz66Q-4hRNnGdEGyOICqFbm4VQ4-ZV7O8fftoznes6-u-6sZyvz8Gp3N3hPLASFvtoWeJBPS8SEE8pPnxD20v8_NPnWLANDG8aFPfquA7RBNHvpEgiH5Q0eIqmtl5k",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehran Now",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehran Now"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 12,
               "value" : "Tehran"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 20,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 37,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Tehran Bazaar, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "7a97ba4c05dcb1b11c2153bd39673b6737aa5748",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJJX5my-8Bjj8RfAUG71zqw8s",
         "reference" : "ClREAAAABs4mvt65BUJ7Z2arVA_cv7V0tdPJKoVy010IOFrlS-L6VfhrEmIQAuxTXVQhnAA19fjEtVbPag3lfb-UrsmnMROnzvXiffA7MKUvgASMwvwSEGx-aGYRXyP1Q9Bxr7HmMVIaFKaxQEb8tg4L7IlRIbITWpG4F5Mf",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehran Bazaar",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehran Bazaar"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 15,
               "value" : "Tehran"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 23,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 40,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political", "geocode" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Now I need to make an autocomplete list of the result. I mean I need to make such a thing:

```
<ul>
  <li>Tehran Province, Iran</li>
  <li>Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran</li>
  <li>Tehranpars, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran</li>
  <li>Tehran Bazaar, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran</li>
</ul>
```

But I don't know how can I select the value of `description` of the result. Here is my code:

```
var html = "<ul>";
$.each(locations.output, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value);
})
var html += "</ul>";

/*
"
p
r
e
d
.
.
.
```

As you can see, the result is lots of single characters. How can I get that values?

Comment: If it's string you can parse it using `JSON.parse(locations.output)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the JavaScript object from the response you can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). This method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string:

```
var response = JSON.parse(locations.output);
```

Than you can use `response` in your code like this:

```js
// Mocking response variable for code example..
var response = {"predictions": [{"description": "Tehran Province, Iran","id": "4c45c924b261e2bb262360fb5a25d4b9a94088a7","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJf5Us9YQBjj8R0OohvHQms1U","reference": "CjQtAAAA6j_9DtMr30DQ9h8dzemfD2NaWEWBgf5yFlQ92XW4EZvHXqZ8Ob6wGkedetO1xNiZEhCGeIk7jBXCQP_ad4V0R-YeGhSIcGtxcxPh-G4e2DMT97Be4xdfkg","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehran Province","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 17,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political", "geocode"]},{"description": "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran","id": "14788d031b564588682273730e2e16d2617d3548","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJ2dzzH0kAjj8RvCRwVnxps_A","reference": "CkQ1AAAAGXsNCFct3XK9JukMD-C7D7j1f0b-Rk0uBZFULZ9TKziZVKz2HWeNWZ5xWU-aNIceYEioJRxHmYS_O7DhMW32YBIQzGS_zTt6aijJx_onRU9DTRoU-cPuoOF16KrzlFY_4EGlwVf1Izk","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehran","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Tehran Province, Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehran"},{"offset": 8,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 25,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["locality", "political", "geocode"]},{"description": "Tehranpars, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran","id": "09a979a1ac286c1ff2ee94c5d36258910d7f6ec6","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJX5PM9hwdjj8R6zn_mu5suoE","reference": "ClRBAAAACKbtLWiAm5kV0JzYtPOLhQTuMxlMMIXxPGRmuLUF7xuAlx7Mueo91OuJmB4mTwo3T0NhnNhamVDUsKFE0fNffkZi1Bv-ZQs1TcXLNx195C0SELOTSsOMn6pYeSnFMtvVqsIaFCxWipFk_wIxDKVoLi8Cd8g993cG","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehranpars","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehranpars"},{"offset": 12,"value": "Tehran"},{"offset": 20,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 37,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["neighborhood", "political", "geocode"]},{"description": "Tehran Now, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran","id": "1f7583f258e7e92f03b818ba10c48e20d2bd9f59","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJ61k7RLICjj8RnvjuZpbZeEM","reference": "ClRBAAAAydlnsS8Fjw9ibBXXX-XS4xuY4-7yEqMSZNTz66Q-4hRNnGdEGyOICqFbm4VQ4-ZV7O8fftoznes6-u-6sZyvz8Gp3N3hPLASFvtoWeJBPS8SEE8pPnxD20v8_NPnWLANDG8aFPfquA7RBNHvpEgiH5Q0eIqmtl5k","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehran Now","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehran Now"},{"offset": 12,"value": "Tehran"},{"offset": 20,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 37,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political", "geocode"]},{"description": "Tehran Bazaar, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran","id": "7a97ba4c05dcb1b11c2153bd39673b6737aa5748","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJJX5my-8Bjj8RfAUG71zqw8s","reference": "ClREAAAABs4mvt65BUJ7Z2arVA_cv7V0tdPJKoVy010IOFrlS-L6VfhrEmIQAuxTXVQhnAA19fjEtVbPag3lfb-UrsmnMROnzvXiffA7MKUvgASMwvwSEGx-aGYRXyP1Q9Bxr7HmMVIaFKaxQEb8tg4L7IlRIbITWpG4F5Mf","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehran Bazaar","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehran Bazaar"},{"offset": 15,"value": "Tehran"},{"offset": 23,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 40,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["neighborhood", "political", "geocode"]}], "status": "OK"};
var html = '<ul>';

$.each(response.predictions, function (index, value) {
  html += '<li>' + value.description + '</li>';
});
html += '</ul>';

$('#output').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: You've made a valid object and initialized it to `locations` variable. While in reality, the whole that result is just a string.

Comment: Thanks @stack... Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7d0tgdL2/)

HTML :

```
<div id="myListDiv">

</div>
```

Your result data :

```
var result = {
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "4c45c924b261e2bb262360fb5a25d4b9a94088a7",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJf5Us9YQBjj8R0OohvHQms1U",
         "reference" : "CjQtAAAA6j_9DtMr30DQ9h8dzemfD2NaWEWBgf5yFlQ92XW4EZvHXqZ8Ob6wGkedetO1xNiZEhCGeIk7jBXCQP_ad4V0R-YeGhSIcGtxcxPh-G4e2DMT97Be4xdfkg",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehran Province",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 17,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "14788d031b564588682273730e2e16d2617d3548",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2dzzH0kAjj8RvCRwVnxps_A",
         "reference" : "CkQ1AAAAGXsNCFct3XK9JukMD-C7D7j1f0b-Rk0uBZFULZ9TKziZVKz2HWeNWZ5xWU-aNIceYEioJRxHmYS_O7DhMW32YBIQzGS_zTt6aijJx_onRU9DTRoU-cPuoOF16KrzlFY_4EGlwVf1Izk",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehran",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Tehran Province, Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehran"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 8,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 25,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Tehranpars, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "09a979a1ac286c1ff2ee94c5d36258910d7f6ec6",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJX5PM9hwdjj8R6zn_mu5suoE",
         "reference" : "ClRBAAAACKbtLWiAm5kV0JzYtPOLhQTuMxlMMIXxPGRmuLUF7xuAlx7Mueo91OuJmB4mTwo3T0NhnNhamVDUsKFE0fNffkZi1Bv-ZQs1TcXLNx195C0SELOTSsOMn6pYeSnFMtvVqsIaFCxWipFk_wIxDKVoLi8Cd8g993cG",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehranpars",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehranpars"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 12,
               "value" : "Tehran"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 20,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 37,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Tehran Now, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "1f7583f258e7e92f03b818ba10c48e20d2bd9f59",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ61k7RLICjj8RnvjuZpbZeEM",
         "reference" : "ClRBAAAAydlnsS8Fjw9ibBXXX-XS4xuY4-7yEqMSZNTz66Q-4hRNnGdEGyOICqFbm4VQ4-ZV7O8fftoznes6-u-6sZyvz8Gp3N3hPLASFvtoWeJBPS8SEE8pPnxD20v8_NPnWLANDG8aFPfquA7RBNHvpEgiH5Q0eIqmtl5k",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehran Now",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehran Now"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 12,
               "value" : "Tehran"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 20,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 37,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Tehran Bazaar, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran",
         "id" : "7a97ba4c05dcb1b11c2153bd39673b6737aa5748",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJJX5my-8Bjj8RfAUG71zqw8s",
         "reference" : "ClREAAAABs4mvt65BUJ7Z2arVA_cv7V0tdPJKoVy010IOFrlS-L6VfhrEmIQAuxTXVQhnAA19fjEtVbPag3lfb-UrsmnMROnzvXiffA7MKUvgASMwvwSEGx-aGYRXyP1Q9Bxr7HmMVIaFKaxQEb8tg4L7IlRIbITWpG4F5Mf",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Tehran Bazaar",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Tehran Bazaar"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 15,
               "value" : "Tehran"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 23,
               "value" : "Tehran Province"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 40,
               "value" : "Iran"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political", "geocode" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
};
```

The part extracting data :

```
var html = "<ul>";

for (i = 0; i < result.predictions.length; i++) { 
   html += "<li>"+result.predictions[i].description+"</li>";
}

html += "</ul>";

var mydiv = document.getElementById('myListDiv').innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

If locations.output is a string, then you need to use JSON.parse(locations.output) in order to get a json object from it.

Once you do that, you will be able to loop through the predictions:

`var output = JSON.parse(locations.output);
$.each(output.predictions, function(value, index) { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues here. The first issue is you are iterating over a string, instead you need to parse it as a javascript object. Second issue, you need to iterate over an array, not an object. it would look something like this:

```
var html = "<ul>";
$.each(JSON.parse(locations.output.predictions), function (index, value) {
    console.log(value, value.description);
})
var html += "</ul>";
```

You could also use jquery JSON parse method.

```
$.each($.parseJSON(locations.output.predictions), function (index, value) {
    console.log(value, value.description);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result is a JSON string, then you need to convert to a JSON object to iterate through. For demonstration purposes `locations.output` is equivalent to `locationsJSONString` in my snippet. See snippet and comments below.

[JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jwhite052/fsL7024e/16/)

```js
var locationsJSONString = '{"predictions": [{"description": "Tehran Province, Iran","id": "4c45c924b261e2bb262360fb5a25d4b9a94088a7","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJf5Us9YQBjj8R0OohvHQms1U","reference": "CjQtAAAA6j_9DtMr30DQ9h8dzemfD2NaWEWBgf5yFlQ92XW4EZvHXqZ8Ob6wGkedetO1xNiZEhCGeIk7jBXCQP_ad4V0R-YeGhSIcGtxcxPh-G4e2DMT97Be4xdfkg","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehran Province","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 17,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political", "geocode"]},{"description": "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran","id": "14788d031b564588682273730e2e16d2617d3548","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJ2dzzH0kAjj8RvCRwVnxps_A","reference": "CkQ1AAAAGXsNCFct3XK9JukMD-C7D7j1f0b-Rk0uBZFULZ9TKziZVKz2HWeNWZ5xWU-aNIceYEioJRxHmYS_O7DhMW32YBIQzGS_zTt6aijJx_onRU9DTRoU-cPuoOF16KrzlFY_4EGlwVf1Izk","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehran","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Tehran Province, Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehran"},{"offset": 8,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 25,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["locality", "political", "geocode"]},{"description": "Tehranpars, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran","id": "09a979a1ac286c1ff2ee94c5d36258910d7f6ec6","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJX5PM9hwdjj8R6zn_mu5suoE","reference": "ClRBAAAACKbtLWiAm5kV0JzYtPOLhQTuMxlMMIXxPGRmuLUF7xuAlx7Mueo91OuJmB4mTwo3T0NhnNhamVDUsKFE0fNffkZi1Bv-ZQs1TcXLNx195C0SELOTSsOMn6pYeSnFMtvVqsIaFCxWipFk_wIxDKVoLi8Cd8g993cG","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehranpars","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehranpars"},{"offset": 12,"value": "Tehran"},{"offset": 20,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 37,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["neighborhood", "political", "geocode"]},{"description": "Tehran Now, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran","id": "1f7583f258e7e92f03b818ba10c48e20d2bd9f59","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJ61k7RLICjj8RnvjuZpbZeEM","reference": "ClRBAAAAydlnsS8Fjw9ibBXXX-XS4xuY4-7yEqMSZNTz66Q-4hRNnGdEGyOICqFbm4VQ4-ZV7O8fftoznes6-u-6sZyvz8Gp3N3hPLASFvtoWeJBPS8SEE8pPnxD20v8_NPnWLANDG8aFPfquA7RBNHvpEgiH5Q0eIqmtl5k","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehran Now","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehran Now"},{"offset": 12,"value": "Tehran"},{"offset": 20,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 37,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political", "geocode"]},{"description": "Tehran Bazaar, Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran","id": "7a97ba4c05dcb1b11c2153bd39673b6737aa5748","matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"place_id": "ChIJJX5my-8Bjj8RfAUG71zqw8s","reference": "ClREAAAABs4mvt65BUJ7Z2arVA_cv7V0tdPJKoVy010IOFrlS-L6VfhrEmIQAuxTXVQhnAA19fjEtVbPag3lfb-UrsmnMROnzvXiffA7MKUvgASMwvwSEGx-aGYRXyP1Q9Bxr7HmMVIaFKaxQEb8tg4L7IlRIbITWpG4F5Mf","structured_formatting": {"main_text": "Tehran Bazaar","main_text_matched_substrings": [{"length": 6,"offset": 0}],"secondary_text": "Tehran, Tehran Province, Iran"},"terms": [{"offset": 0,"value": "Tehran Bazaar"},{"offset": 15,"value": "Tehran"},{"offset": 23,"value": "Tehran Province"},{"offset": 40,"value": "Iran"}],"types": ["neighborhood", "political", "geocode"]}], "status": "OK"}';

// convert the JSON string into an object
var locationsJSONObj = JSON.parse(locationsJSONString);

// the results are stored in the "predictions" property of the object
// the value is an array which we assign to the variable below
// to iterate over
var locationsPredictionsArray = locationsJSONObj.predictions;

// format result in list element
var html = '<ul>';

$.each(locationsPredictionsArray, function (index, value) {
 // add item for each location description
  html += '<li>' + value.description + '</li>';
});
html += '</ul>';

$('#output').html(html); // show output in html element
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```